# Rails Bootstrap dynamic tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dynamic, tabular

I currently have an application that allows users to access a location and within that location, associated products exist.

Right now they are just listed in a table.

I would like to convert that table into tabular style so more detail about that product can be listed inside.

I was studying the tabular bootstrap but most examples are based on static content, not dynamic.

When a product is created on the back end and assigned to a certain location, I would need a tab to auto generate with the title of the product and then have the content associated with that product as well.

Want to display content in same location view and not redirect user to another page when they click on the tab name.

Can anyone suggest a place to start?

**Products Partial**

```
 <table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <% @products.each do |product| %>
     <tr>
        <td><%= product.name %></td>
     </tr>
    <% end %>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

This seems to work but does not look DRY

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   <% @products.each do |product| %>
   <li><a href="#<%= product.id %>" data-toggle="tab"><%= product.name %></a></li>
 <% end %>
 </ul>
 <div class="tab-content">
<% @products.each do |product| %>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="<%= product.id %>"><%= product.sku %></div>
<% end %>
 </div>
```

Comment: Its NOT not DRY - you're not repeating anything except the `@products.each` - which is fine. I wouldn't get too caught up in the "gotta be DRY or die" mania.

Comment: The difficulty here is generating the content in each of the tab?